# Как сократить ссылку через goo-gl.me или goo.su API на python

Tags: python, ссылки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно через API goo-gl.me сокращать ссылки на python. Документация есть: https://goo-gl.me/api-docs и я ее читал, токен получил, но вообще ничего не понял. Пробовал через bitly, но там на бесплатном аккаунте до 100 ссылок в месяц - не подходит. Возможно есть другие альтернативы с неограниченным количеством сокращений?

Или через сервис https://goo.su/api, в документации есть вот такой пример запроса и ответа, но как питоном это передать не понимаю..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй лучше эту сокращалку https://goo-gl.ink/
Там апи получше и нет ограничений никаких Вот дока https://goo-gl.ink/developers